# Turn on laptop from external keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard, bios

I would like to turn on my laptop from an external keyboard. I have two monitors and I don't need to have an open laptop.

I know there are some BIOS options related to turning on by an external keyboard but in my Lenovo IdeaPad 700-15isk I couldn't find any right option.

Is it possible to somehow set it up from Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

You would either need the specific option (which you do not have) or a Dock that specifically supports that. There certainly are Docks that have an external power button that does require the laptop lid to be open

Otherwise, no, the external keyboard will not turn on the laptop.

The ability to do this is not very common, except as noted above.